# AWS preassigned url as eks token is giving unauthorized

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, authorization, amazon-eks

I am using below code to interact with EKS apiserver with preassigned url created with my service account credentials. But it's giving unauthorized:

```py
"Lambda function list pods in EKS cluster"
import base64
import os
import logging
import re
import boto3

from botocore.signers import RequestSigner
from kubernetes import client, config
from botocore.session import Session


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

STS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN = 60
cluster_name = <EKS_CLUSTER_NAME>

eks = boto3.client('eks', aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_KEY>, aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_KEY>, region_name=<CLUSTER_REGION>)

cluster_cache = {}

def get_session_token(access_key, secret_key, region):
    # Create an STS client
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, region_name=region)
 
    session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    region_name=region)
    return session

def get_cluster_info():
    "Retrieve cluster endpoint and certificate"

    cluster_info = eks.describe_cluster(name=cluster_name)
    endpoint = cluster_info['cluster']['endpoint']
    cert_authority = cluster_info['cluster']['certificateAuthority']['data']
    cluster_info = {
        "endpoint" : endpoint,
        "ca" : cert_authority
    }
    return cluster_info

def get_bearer_token():
    "Create authentication token"
    session = get_session_token(<ACCESS_KEY>, <SECRET_KEY>, <REGION>);
    sts = session.client('sts')
    service_id = sts.meta.service_model.service_id
    signer = RequestSigner(
        service_id,
        <REGION>,
        'sts',
        'v4',
        session.get_credentials(),
        session.events
    )

    params = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'https://sts.amazonaws.com/'
               '?Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15',
        'body': {},
        'headers': {
            'x-k8s-aws-id': cluster_name
        },
        'context': {}
    }

    signed_url = signer.generate_presigned_url(
        params,
        region_name=session.region_name,
        expires_in=40000,
        operation_name=''
    )
    base64_url = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signed_url.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

    # remove any base64 encoding padding:
    return 'k8s-aws-v1.' + re.sub(r'=*', '', base64_url)


def lambda_handler(_event, _context):
    "Lambda handler"
    if cluster_name in cluster_cache:
        cluster = cluster_cache[cluster_name]
    else:
        # not present in cache retrieve cluster info from EKS service
        cluster = get_cluster_info()
        # store in cache for execution environment resuse
        cluster_cache[cluster_name] = cluster

    kubeconfig = {
        'apiVersion': 'v1',
        'clusters': [{
          'name': 'cluster1',
          'cluster': {
            'certificate-authority-data': cluster["ca"],
            'server': cluster["endpoint"]}
        }],
        'contexts': [{'name': 'context1', 'context': {'cluster': 'cluster1', "user": "user1"}}],
        'current-context': 'context1',
        'kind': 'Config',
        'preferences': {},
        'users': [{'name': 'user1', "user" : {'token': get_bearer_token()}}]
    }

    config.load_kube_config_from_dict(config_dict=kubeconfig)
    v1_api = client.CoreV1Api() # api_client
    ret = v1_api.list_namespaced_pod("default")
    return f"There are {len(ret.items)} pods in the default namespace."

print(lambda_handler(None, None))
```

I just want to create eks token so that I can use that to communicate with eks cluster. And here I don't want to use aws cli.

This is the error response:

kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '<audit_id>', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Wed, 31 Jan 2024 11:09:47 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}

Comment: Please post the exact error it's giving and the call stack.

Comment: kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'audit_id', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Wed, 31 Jan 2024 11:09:47 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}